# Make turtles that only differ in color do something different from each other

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am making a code including turtles. I want different colored turtles to do something different. How can I make this work? Is this possible?

I tried something like below, but I don't think it works.

```
if turtle.color() == "blue":
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
if turtle.color() == "blue":
    ...
else:
    ...
```

because `color()` returns a pair of colors, the `pencolor()` and the `fillcolor()`:

```
>>> turtle.color()
('blue', 'red')
>>>
```

You can continue to use `color()` to set the color, but use `pencolor()` to test the color:

```
>>> turtle.pencolor()
'blue'
>>>
```

In the case of your code:

```
if turtle.pencolor() == "blue":
    ...
else:
    ...
```